# Next line in hta/html

Tags: html, text

I am trying to get an out put line this:

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
```

I have tried the following:

```
<p>Line 1
Line 2
Line 3</p>
```

But i get:

```
Line 1 Line 2 Line 3
```

I have also tried this:

```
<p>Line 1</p>
<p>Line 2</p>
<p>Line 3</p>
```

But I get this with massive spaces between the lines.

```
Line 1

Line 2

Line 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<br />` tags, or look at using some CSS to redefine the margin and padding on your `<p>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

use `<br>` for break the line.